# How to assign value based on string match in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have two dataframe:

```
DF_1

ID      Value1
1       Lion
2       Cat
3       Elephant
4       Lion -s

DF_2

Value2          Assign
Lion - X        AD
Cat as          FD
Elephant -92    DS
Viper           AB
Fish ws r       DF
```

I want to match `Value1` of DF_1 with `Value2` of DF_2, for any similar value of DF_1 in DF_2 assign the from `Assign` column of DF_2 in new output dataframe (using merge based on the `Value1`).

The above mentioned dataframes are only for sample, i have very big dataframe with different `Value1` but there would be similarity in `Value1` and `Value2` value of both the dataframe.

Required Output:

```
ID      Value1     Assign
1       Lion       AD
2       Cat        FD
3       Elephant   DS
4       Lion -s    AD
```

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? Up to the first space?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Yes but it could be any thing, i,e first "-" or any other symbol.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns If there are `Lion<4?2` and `lion s` and `Lion-xe` than all should be assign value `AD`

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to extract the first "word" via regex and then match on the lowercase version of that extraction:

```
library(tidyverse)

DF_1 <- data_frame(
  ID = 1:7,
  Value1 = c('Lion', 'Cat', 'Elephant', 'Lion -s', 'Lion<4?2', 'lion s', 'Lion-xe')
)

DF_2 <- data_frame(
  Value2 = c('Lion - X', 'Cat as', 'Elephant -92', 'Viper', 'Fish ws r'),
  Assign = c('AD', 'FD', 'DS', 'AB', 'DF')
)

DF_1$first_word <- str_extract(DF_1$Value1, "\\w+") %>% str_to_lower()
DF_2$first_word <- str_extract(DF_2$Value2, "\\w+") %>% str_to_lower()

DF_1 %>%
  left_join(DF_2, by = "first_word")
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>      ID Value1   first_word Value2       Assign
#>   <int> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>        <chr> 
#> 1     1 Lion     lion       Lion - X     AD    
#> 2     2 Cat      cat        Cat as       FD    
#> 3     3 Elephant elephant   Elephant -92 DS    
#> 4     4 Lion -s  lion       Lion - X     AD    
#> 5     5 Lion<4?2 lion       Lion - X     AD    
#> 6     6 lion s   lion       Lion - X     AD    
#> 7     7 Lion-xe  lion       Lion - X     AD
```

Comment: Not getting the `Assign` column while left join.

Comment: and i have some cases where first word approach didn't work (i.e Where Lion - Cat   Assign `DV` and Lion - xe Assign `AD`)

Comment: Can you help me over here.

Comment: A few things, I'm not sure why you do not receive the `Assign` column, my code above is reproducible. When you say, "you have some cases..." this means your question and articulated cases are incomplete. For example, there is no `DV` value in your provided `DF_2` data.frame. At this point, you may want to take any learnings from this question and either heavily edit your original question or post a new one.

Comment: I have run your reproducible code, the output is showing in console but not storing in DF_1

Comment: Agreed that i have missed some part in the question, but if you understand my question now, can you help me here.??

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to answer yet (again, where is `DV`? How would anyone know `Lion - Cat` goes to `DV` and not to `AD` nor `FD`?). It's not storing in `DF_1` because we have not stored it yet. To store it you would have to do: `DF_1 <- DF_1 %>%
  left_join(DF_2, by = "first_word")`